# "sterilizing" a flower bed

Tags: weed-control

We recently moved into a new house that has a flower bed that is completely infested with weeds. It's basically solid weeds. We spent the day hand-weeding and getting rid of most of what we can see.

What else can/should we do to prevent the weeds from returning? Have we done enough?

We plan on planting annual wildflowers, which I guess are sort of weeds themselves. Also, we plan on planting strawberries.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the thing, no matter what you do the weeds will return. Eventually. Here are some things you can do to slow them down.

- put down some weed blocking fabric (available in your hardware store or wal-mart).
- mulch around your new flowers when they come up
- weed regularly

It's hard work keeping a bed free of unwanted plants, there is no magic solution and the things I mentioned above are deterrents, the weeds will eventually come back, because good healthy soil, the kind you want for your plants, is exactly the thing they crave.

Answer (score 5):

Cover the bed with black plastic for a week or two.  If the weather is warm, this will kill weeds and their seeds.